# Looking for a single value in an Excel column with multiple matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of client numbers and I need to search through a list of account numbers to find out if the client has a particular account number in their file.

My original sheet looks like this

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oh3t.jpg)

My list of account numbers looks like this

- 217   1008
- 218   1008
- 219   1008
- 217   2009
- 218   2009
- 219   2009
- 218   3015
- 219   3015
- 217   4017
- 219   4017

Expected results look like this

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE3r3.jpg)

Originally, I concatenated the client and account numbers then did a VLOOKUP but I'm sure there's a better way. Maybe using VBA instead of a formula in the worksheet.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by PT?

Comment: PT = `Pivot Table` :)

Comment: [tag:VBA] might be over-kill for this. There's a couple of formula-based methods suggested below, e.g `COUNTIFS` and `MATCH` (my own) both work well.

Comment: Nice question, I didn't realize there'd be so many non-VBA ways to do this. Lots of little tricks in the answers below.

Comment: @pnuts... as they say `all good programmers are lazy` :)

Comment: @pnuts totally agree, they are synonyms.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Client and Accounts list is in seperate cells, you could use `Countifs()`:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  I don't know why the simplest answers elude me.  The VBA solution is definitely overkill.

Answer (score 1):

As @pnuts says, a PivotTable will get you your results table, but it will soon get unwieldy if you have large numbers of clients/accounts. Your VLOOKUP of a CONCATENATEd value is a good way to go unless you don't want to modify the data.

If you're only doing it as a single shot check on a small number of clients/accounts, perhaps just using the auto-filters on the data might be a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you Client and Accounts is in the same column, you can use this which tries to `MATCH` the concatenation of the row and column header (with space):

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($C4&" "&D$1,$A$2:$A$11,0))),"X","")
```

E.g.:

[image]

Comment: They are in separate columns

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the the table shown in results starts in cell A1, so your formula will be typed in B3 and copied right and down. I will also assume you account list is in a named range `Acct`.

```
=IF(MATCH($A3&" "&B$14,Acct)>0,"X","")
```

Copy this to all cells in B3:E5 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using `Index/Match`. Break your `217 1008` column into two, using Text to Columns, Space Delimiter.  Then say these are in range J1:J10 (`217, 218, etc.`), and in K1:K10 is `1008, 1009, etc.`:

`=IF(NOT(ISERROR(INDEX($J$1:$J$10,MATCH($A2&B$1,$J$1:$J$10&$K$1:$K$10,0)))),"X","")`
(enter as array with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

Where A2 is the start of your `217` numbers going down, and B1 is the `1008` start going right.